# Cannot add a standard map marker to a google map with heatmap layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with a heatmap utilizing the [google visualization heatmap layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#HeatmapLayer)

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kevmc2/P6Mp5/1/)

If I try and add a normal map marker it fails with an uncaught type error somewhere in the google api.

The `marker.setMap(map)` line seems to happen, (inspecting the marker, it has a map property) but whatever this triggers on the map itself seems to fall over.

I've tried unsetting the heatmap layer before setting the marker, even tried not initialising the heatmap layer with the same results.

I'm beginning to think that by including the visualisation library I am losing the ability to add a map marker.  If this is the case has anyone come across a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initially create the marker without a map-property, currently the marker will appear when you click somewhere (not only on the marker), because the `lnk`-variable will be set to `document`, not to the link:

```
 var lnk = $(document, '.marker_toggle')
```

but it should be only:

```
 var lnk = $('.marker_toggle')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Avxap/

Comment: Well spotted, hopefully I'll find a similar scoping problem on the real site ;)